# Error in Flutter Project Migration: _FakeScrollContext Missing Implementation for devicePixelRatio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, migration

I'm currently facing a challenging issue while migrating my Flutter project from version 3.7.12 to the latest version. After successfully updating all the plugins to their latest versions and upgrading Flutter itself, I'm encountering the following error when attempting to run the app:

```
: Error: The non-abstract class '_FakeScrollContext' is missing implementations for these members:
scrolls_to_top.dart:112

ScrollContext.devicePixelRatio
Try to either
provide an implementation,
inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
mark the class as abstract, or
provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
class _FakeScrollContext extends ScrollContext {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Context: 'ScrollContext.devicePixelRatio' is defined here.
scroll_context.dart:47
double get devicePixelRatio;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Cruxule Dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

In an attempt to resolve this, I followed these steps:

1. Updated all plugins to their latest versions.
2. Upgraded Flutter itself to the latest version.
3. Tried cleaning the project using `flutter clean`.
4. Deleted the 'build' directory to ensure no cached artifacts are causing the issue.
5. Created a new Flutter project from scratch and copied over the 'lib', 'assets', and 'pubspec.yaml' files. Remarkably, the new project runs without encountering any errors.

To provide more context, the interesting aspect is that the new Flutter project works perfectly fine before copying and pasting the code from my original project. Once I copy and paste the code into the new project, I encounter this error. This suggests that there might be some incompatibility between my original code and the new environment, but I'm unsure what exactly is causing it.

I've already tried updating plugins, upgrading Flutter, cleaning the project, and deleting the 'build' directory, all without success.

Has anyone faced a similar issue during project migration, especially when copy-pasting code? I'd greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or tips on how to identify the root cause of this issue and successfully migrate my project.

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: How do I stop the scroll Behaviour with the scrollController object?